# concatenate latitude and longiude to strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

```
array = response.split(",")
lat=array[3]
print lat
lon=array[4]
print(lon)
stringlink="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat,lon
print(stringlink)
return(lat,lon)
```

I want to concatenate the lat and lon to stringlink and send it over gsm module . I am not getting how to concatenate them. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.format`.

**Ex:**

```
link="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:{0},{1}".format(lat, lon)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much man. I got it executed perfectly .  You know how to send this stringlink via GSM module as a text message ?

Comment: sorry i have not used the GSM module. But let me check if i can find out how to send

Comment: port.write("AT+CMGF=1"+"\r\n")  # Select Message format as Text mode
rcv = port.read(10)
print (rcv)
time.sleep(1)

port.write('AT+CMGS="+917276361328"'+'\r\n')
rcv = port.read(10)
print (rcv)
time.sleep(1)

port.write('Hello User'+'\r\n')  # Message
rcv = port.read(10)
print (rcv)

Comment: instead of hello user how to add my stringlink there ?

Comment: you can try: port.write(stringlink+'\r\n')

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept ans if it solved your problem.Thanks.